# How can I call an API 2 million times quickly and write the returned value into my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rest, fetch-api

I have a problem. I have a dataframe that contains two addresses `fromLat`, `fromLong` to `toLat`, `toLong`. From these two addresses I want to calculate the distance by car and the duration. For this I use the following API from [project-osrm](http://project-osrm.org/) . Unfortunately, the way I do it is very slow. I have about 2 million rows in my dataframe and for each one I would like to measure the `duration` and the `distance`. I have found the following code snippet (see below). However, I don't know how to integrate my dataframe so that it passes the values.

> How can I call an API 2 million times quickly and write the returned
> value into my dataframe?

- If I don't get a status code `200` back, I should just write None for `distance` and `duration`.

Dataframe

```py
   customerId    fromLat     fromLong      toLat       toLong
0           1  48.103190    11.601773  53.446762    10.061031
1           2  48.541160     2.628249  41.374426     2.037211
2           2  25.907100  -100.338113  23.994722  -104.754147
3           3  41.948767    12.742488  49.316171   -33.968543
4           3       None         None  41.948767    12.742488
```

Code with MVC

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "customerId": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "fromLat": ["48.103190","48.541160", "25.907100", "41.948767", None],
     "fromLong": ["11.601773", "2.628249", "-100.338113", "12.742488", None],
     "toLat": ["53.446762", "41.374426", "23.994722", "49.316171", "41.948767"],
     "toLong": ["10.061031", "2.037211", "-104.754147", "-33.968543", "12.742488"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

import requests
import json

def f(x):
  url = f"http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{x['fromLat']},{x['fromLong']};{x['toLat']},{x['toLong']}?overview=false"
  r = requests.get(url)

  print(r.status_code, r.reason)

  if (r.status_code == 200):
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    x['distance']  = data['routes'][0]['distance']
    x['duration'] = data['routes'][0]['duration']
  else:
    x['distance'] = None
    x['duration']= None
  return x

df = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=1)
```

What I want (note: `duration` and `distance` are only example values)

```py
   customerId    fromLat     fromLong      toLat       toLong  Distance Duration
0           1  48.103190    11.601773  53.446762    10.061031       500      785
1           2  48.541160     2.628249  41.374426     2.037211      4784      474
2           2  25.907100  -100.338113  23.994722  -104.754147       147      987
3           3  41.948767    12.742488  49.316171   -33.968543      None     None
4           3       None         None  41.948767    12.742488      None     None
```

Code found at [Github](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html)

```py
# modified fetch function with semaphore
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        delay = response.headers.get("DELAY")
        date = response.headers.get("DATE")
        print("{}:{} with delay {}".format(date, response.url, delay))
        return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def run(r):
    url = f"http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{fromLat},{fromLong};{toLat},{toLong}?overview=false"
    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per each request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

number = df.shape[0]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: is this api made for 2 million requests? you would want (technically) an API that allows you to submit batches of requests and (commercially) allows you submit millions of requests.

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing it out. I haven't really found anything on that. In an emergency (if it doesn't work), I could also reduce the dataframe to less (about 100k). The project is not commercial but for research purposes without benefits behind it.

Comment: Also, check with that API provider if they have a "bulk" input support, for e.g they could take an uri as input , that can have a csv or json file for which they need to find the result and give back a file/blob

Comment: If the API provider allows 2m HTTP requests from the same origin (which I doubt) then running the requests synchronously and assuming each request takes one second, your application would run for ~23 days. Multithreading would help you significantly but you really need to check if OSRM will allow such high volumes

Comment: @AlbertWinestein I look and `Do not exceed 1 request per second.`. But nonetheless, if the API were adopted it could handle so many requests. How could I write the API request?

Comment: @Test I guess the "Do not exceed..." Information comes from OSRM so are you saying to want to run this synchronously and also ensure that you don't make more than 1 request per second? And you're happy for your program to run for almost a month?

Comment: No. I mean suppose the API I would use could accept multiple requests per second. How could I then rewrite the code so that the dataframe gives the values to the API call on the one hand and receives them again on the other.

Answer (score 1):

OSRM also offers a [C++ library](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.24.0/api/#introduction):

> OSRM can be used as a library (libosrm) via C++ instead of using it through the HTTP interface and osrm-routed. This allows for fine-tuning OSRM and has much less overhead. Here is a quick introduction into how to use libosrm in the upcoming v5 release.

This is probably the way to go if you want to query many routes.

Comment: I have no idea about C++ and how do I get the values from my dataframe and add them back to my dataframe later?

Comment: Do you know about C++ and python bindings? Anyway, the C++ library is clearly the answer if you need 2 million queries with a rate limit of 1 per second.

Answer (score 1):

When I do scraping / massive API calling I usually use the good old `joblib` threading. Here is a general code snippet that should work:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import pandas ad pd
import requests
import json

# the function you want to parallelize
def f(x):

    # request
    res = requests.get(
        (
            f"http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/"
            f"{x['fromLat']},{x['fromLong']};{x['toLat']},{x['toLong']}"
            f"?overview=false"
        )
    )

    # parse output into a dict if valid
    if (res.status_code == 200):
        data = json.loads(res.text)
        output = {
            "customerId": x["customerId"],
            "distance"  : data['routes'][0]['distance'],
            "duration"  : data['routes'][0]['duration']
        }

    # output dict if request failed
    else:
        output = {
            "customerId": x["customerId"],
            "distance"  : float("nan"),
            "duration"  : float("nan")
        }
    
    return output

# run f(x) in parallel, where x is a row of your df
outputs = Parallel(n_jobs=16, backend="threading")(
    delayed(f)(x) for x in df.iterrows()
)

# create pandas df from the list of output dicts
outputs_df = pd.DataFrame(outputs)
```

Pay attention to the `n_jobs` arg of `Parallel`. It is responsible for the number of concurrent executions of `f(x)`. If you are hitting some kind of API limit due to number of requests, you can add `time.sleep(some_number_of_seconds)` from `time` module anywhere in the `f(x)` code to add delay on each request.

Hope this was useful :)